# Can not put a T in Map<String, ? extends T>

Tags: java, generics

```java
private static final Map<String, ? extends TrackingInterface<TrackResponseObject>> map = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        map.put("dunzo", new DunzoShipment());
        map.put("self", new SelfShipment());
    }
```

```java
public class DunzoShipment implements TrackingInterface<TrackResponseObject>,java.util.function.Supplier<TrackingInterface<TrackResponseObject>> { 
//body
}
```

while puting the object into map i am getting an error:

> The method put(String, capture#1-of ? extends TrackingInterface) in the type Map<String,capture#1-of ? extends TrackingInterface> is not applicable for the arguments (String, DunzoShipment)

Comment: If both of the shipment class are implementing the same `TrackingInterface` then there is no need for the wildcard there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
? extends TrackingInterface
```

means "*something* which extends `TrackingInterface`". We don't know what that *something* is, so we can't be sure that `DunzoShipment` is one of them. That's why you can't insert into the map.

[PECS: producer extends, consumer super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). This is a consumer (via `put`), so you cannot use `extends`.

Just remove the `? extends` part and it will compile.